# Spring- Integration technical architecture design

Tags: java, spring, architecture, spring-integration, spring-batch

I started a new project recently and I encounter some problems that I never had before.

I have to develop an application which will work like this:

1. The system listens a JMS queue (where messages are pushed by another system).
2. When a new message arrrives, the system must read the UUID of the bundle (a bundle  is a ZIP file which contains a submission in XML and other file attachments).
3. Based on the UUID, the system must download the bundle using a web services exposed by the other system.
4. The system must unzip the bundle and store the files in a temporay filestore.
5. The system must validate/transform the XML.
6. The system must store the submission in database(s) based on the receiver(s) and copy attachments in filestore(s).
7. The system must store a copy of the submission and the attachements in a secure database (for history and reporting) and filestore.

This is the flow of the future system and I also need to manage the error at each "step" if the system encounters an error during the process.

My questions are :

1. I plan to use Spring Integration but I have never used this module before and I would like to know if it is a good solution for my requirements?
2. I already have a look at project documentation but I don't understand how can I handle the errors during the process ?
3. It is not direcly linked to Spring Integration but at the end of my process, I need to write the submission in 28 "client" databases depending to the content.

Do not hesitate to propose any others solutions/frameworks that can help me in this project. For the moment, I just plan to use Spring Integration because I work with others modules since a long time.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach but your question is mostly off-topic for Stackoverflow the way it is. Instead of a 3-in-1 question research all parts individually. 2 and especially 3 require more detail to be specific enough. 1 is in my opinion too subjective. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask